# jQuery UI Theme Conflict: SlickGrid and jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, slickgrid, jquery-ui-theme

I'm trying to apply this SlickGrid example:

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

to my own web project.

When I drop my grid in to the top of my page, it renders correctly.  However, when I drop it into a jQuery UI Tabs tab on the same page, the CSS Sprite that renders the search image is incorrectly offset.

[image: The Problem]

The icon is rendered with

```
<span title="Toggle search panel" class="ui-icon ui-icon-search ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="float: right;" onclick="toggleFilterRow11()"/>
```

It looks like jQuery UI Tabs also uses the same CSS classes, and of course a conflict arises.

Looking at the effective styles in IE9, the control outside of jQuery UI Tabs that renders correctly has the following:

[image: Correct styles]

The control that renders incorrectly looks like this:

[image: Wrong styles]

**Bottom Line**

Placing the SlickGrid in a jQueryUI Tab causes the `ui-icon-search` class to be lost and therefore the wrong `background-position-x/y` to be set.

Why is that class being lost and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The problem

When jQueryUI creates tabs from the HTML it adds the jQueryUI CSS classes. From the jQueryUI examples:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is happening because the [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) content now exits as a child of an element with the class `ui-widget-content`. Actually, there are 2 ancestors of the *grid header* that have that class - in the above code see `<div id="tabs">` and `<div id="tabs-1">` both have that class applied when tabs are created.

The jQueryUI CSS rules that are supposed to apply to get the correct search icon are:

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}

.ui-icon-search {
    background-position: -160px -112px;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555;
}
```

The markup for the icon is:

```
<span style="float:right" class="ui-icon ui-icon-search ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Toggle search panel" onclick="toggleFilterRow()"></span>
```

so therefore the CSS rules `.ui-icon`, `.ui-icon-search` and the *first* match of the 3rd rule `.ui-state-default` are applied.

However when the same markup exists as a descendent of a element with the class `.ui-widget-content`, the 2nd part of the 3rd rule above (`.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default`) also matches which is **more specific**. See http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg for a Star Wars themed explaination of *CSS specificity*. Essentially the `background` property of the 3rd rule that includes `background-position:50% 50%` is more specific than the single selector `.ui-icon-search` rule therefore overriding the correct `background-position:-160px -112px`.

#### The solution

Need to make the `.ui-icon-search` rule the same or more specific than the `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default` rule which can be done by either:

1. Adding `!important` to the rule
2. Adding more selectors to the rule

For example

```
.ui-icon-search {
    background-position: -160px -112px !important;
}
```

or

```
.ui-icon-search, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon-search {
    background-position: -160px -112px;
}
```

I cannot think of a way that doesn't involve changing the jQueryUI CSS (or duplicating the `.ui-icon-search` rule in your own CSS with one of the two solutions above). I would actually be interested to see if there is another way myself!

Comment: That's an awesome explanation.  Wish I could give more than 1 upvote.  I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone can provide a less intrusive solution.